# plot z value in each data point pm3d map

Tags: gnuplot

My question is about my code in gnuplot. I want to plot data with `pm3d` map and Matrix and want to plot the `z` value in each datapoint as well. I tried this:

```
set pm3d;set pm3d interpolate 0,0;set pm3d map;
set Palette rgb 33,13,10;splot 'filepath' Matrix
```

It is all working fine but I cannot plot the `z` values so I tried this one

```
splot 'filepath' Matrix using 1:2:(sprintf(%g,$3)) with labels
```

but this is also not working. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What exactly means "I cannot plot the z values" or "is also not working"? You should provide a complete example with input data which allows others to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

as @Bodo, wrote... "not working" is not enough and not helpful to others.
With your code, you must have gotten some error messages, provide them as well.

Several mistakes in your script:

`set palette` instead of `set Palette`

`splot 'filepath' matrix` instead of `splot 'filepath' Matrix`

`sprintf("%g",$3)` instead of `sprintf(%g,$3)`

To your actual problem:

`splot` requires 3D coordinates + label text, i.e. in your case `x:y:z:z` or `1:2:3:3`

So, the following code is probably doing what you intended to do.

```
set pm3d
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set pm3d map
set palette rgb 33,13,10
splot 'filepath' matrix u 1:2:3:(sprintf("%g",$3)) with labels
```

Comment: Thank you that solved my Problem i just did not know the Right Syntax of the label command but with your Code it is working :) it was just the Problem with as you said the 3d coordinates +label :)

Comment: You're welcome. Although, gnuplot has a rather good manual and help function, it is sometimes difficult to find the right entry or the appropriate example on the demo page http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/ . Don't forget to mark your question as solved, i.e. accepting the answer.